# Laravel 5: Unknown Column when using RAW:: and column alias

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and trying to return a list of Hotels.

I have the users lat/lng and I am using a db::raw statement to calculate the distance from the user to the hotels.  That part works great, in the list of returned Hotels I can easily list the distance using

```
$hotel->distance;
```

For reference:

```
    Hotels = Hotel::select(
                    \DB::raw("*,
                      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) *
                        cos( radians( lat ) )
                        * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ")
                        ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) *
                        sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                      ) AS distance"))
                    ->where('live','=', 1)
```

As you can see, I am using an alias of 'distance' for the on the fly calculation.  Again, this all works great until now.  Now I am attempting to add another Dropdown so a user can select a desired radius (10, 20, 50, 100) miles, etc.

When building my query, I have:

```
if(isset($search['distance'])) $hotels = $hotels->where('distance', '<=', $search['distance']);
```

I do this for a number of optional search paramaters, and then way at the bottom I order them and then GET the result set:

```
$hotels = $hotels->get()
```

The issue I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'
```

And the reason is, at the time I am doing the `where->distance` that column does not yet exist, it doesnt actually appear until I do  `$hotels->get()`  so what are my options?

I could get the results without filtering by distance (lots of results) and then trim them down from there, but that seems unnecessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to prefix your column name with the table name. "hotel.distance"

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For example, the following query is illegal:
>
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;

It is not Laravel related. It is MySQL thing. You can not use where condition on alias, because the conditions are parsed before the result set is fetched, and the alias is applied after the results are selected.

You need to use `HAVING` clause.

```
if(isset($search['distance'])) 
    $hotels = $hotels->having('distance', '<=', $search['distance']);
```

You can read more about [HAVING keyword here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) .

Comment: I think having has the same issue: ``` Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' ```

Comment: @Jay It is working just find. Please post the php code that give you the error after the change.

Comment: No, it's not working just fine, it's the same issue:  if(isset($search['distance'])) $hotels = $hotels->having('distance', '<=', $search['distance']);

Comment: I mean post the whole query from the begining, where you defined the 'distance' in the select. This part I wrote you is ok, your make mistake at the select part.